# Help me to decrease boot time for Ubuntu Core + LXDE-Openbox

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, ubuntu-core, openbox, boot-time

I have this result of the commnad `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

```
graphical.target @1min 41.706s
└─multi-user.target @1min 41.703s
  └─smbd.service @1min 41.278s +423ms
    └─nmbd.service @39.182s +1min 2.092s
      └─network-online.target @39.165s
        └─systemd-resolved.service @36.838s +156ms
          └─network.target @36.827s
            └─wpa_supplicant.service @38.285s +224ms
              └─basic.target @29.932s
                └─sockets.target @29.929s
                  └─snapd.socket @29.897s +28ms
                    └─sysinit.target @29.136s
                      └─systemd-timesyncd.service @27.747s +1.384s
                        └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @26.585s +1.147s
                          └─systemd-journal-flush.service @7.366s +19.214s
                            └─systemd-remount-fs.service @7.094s +267ms
                              └─system.slice @3.316s
                                └─-.slice @3.240s
```

If anyone can help me to get possible faster boot time.

`Laptop config is: 1.6 GHZ, 2GB Ram, Ubuntu Core + LXDE-Openbox`

Result for `systemd-analyze blame` is:

```
1min 1.821s apt-daily.service
    38.185s nmbd.service
    23.610s systemd-journal-flush.service
    21.026s dev-sda2.device
    13.611s apparmor.service
     6.106s lxd-containers.service
     5.962s mysql.service
     5.950s NetworkManager.service
     5.094s udisks2.service
     4.674s accounts-daemon.service
     4.627s ebtables.service
     4.281s ModemManager.service
     3.130s phpsessionclean.service
     2.967s snapd.service
     2.900s lvm2-monitor.service
     2.511s gpu-manager.service
     2.084s apache2.service
     1.980s systemd-udevd.service
     1.975s grub-common.service
     1.861s keyboard-setup.service
     1.687s apt-daily-upgrade.service
     1.637s motd-news.service
     1.528s binfmt-support.service
```

Comment: `nmbd.service` takes a long time. If you don't need it, you can try disabling it. By the way, there is also the command `systemd-analyze blame` which tells you the services that are to blame for long boot time.

Comment: @danzel I have updated my question with the result of `systemd-analyze blame` command. Thanks for your help in advance.